# Чтение строки с табличными данными в массив

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

5 часов мучения, я больше не могу :(
Помогите кто нить сделать эту регулярку.
Нужно это как есть запихнуть в таблицу:

```
     $txt='hostname: Multiplay :: 9mm [RU/UA] PvP [ON]/ [24/7] / Active admin / Airdrop / Events
version : 1068 secure (secure mode enabled, connected to Steam3)
map     : rust_island_2013
players : 7 (50 max)

id                name                                  ping  connected   addr        
76561198088677396 "Орех"                                63    6536s       178.122.231.109
76561198017922716 "zzzVeNoMzzz"                         32    2037s       37.146.158.158
76561198020147964 "Dmitriev ich"                        63    5097s       95.55.114.5 
76561197994420572 "Mr.Green"                            46    1366s       176.193.86.48
76561198090824711 "immortal"                            93    1947s       92.126.67.174
76561198081813212 "Povar"                               93    6571s       178.120.213.112
76561198073954243 "Nice"                                63    1952s       77.122.79.55';

$txt = explode("addr", $txt);
preg_match_all ('/(\\d+).*?(".*?").*?(\\d+).*?(\\d+)(s).*?((?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?))(?![\\d])/is', $txt[1], $matches);
```

Вот как есть: id, name, ping,connected, addr таким столбиком нужно запихать в таблицу :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PVP охохо

```
<?php $text = 'hostname: Multiplay :: 9mm [RU/UA] PvP [ON]/ [24/7] / Active admin / Airdrop / Events
version : 1068 secure (secure mode enabled, connected to Steam3)
map     : rust_island_2013
players : 7 (50 max)

id                name                                  ping  connected   addr        
76561198088677396 "test name                                63    6536s       178.122.231.109
76561198017922716 "zzzVeNoMzzz"                         32    2037s       37.146.158.158
76561198020147964 "Dmitriev ich"                        63    5097s       95.55.114.5 
76561197994420572 "Mr.Green"                            46    1366s       176.193.86.48
76561198090824711 "immortal"                            93    1947s       92.126.67.174
76561198081813212 "Povar"                               93    6571s       178.120.213.112
76561198073954243 "Nice"                                63    1952s       77.122.79.55';
$pos = strpos($text, 'addr');
$text = trim(substr($text, $pos + 4));
preg_match_all('#(\d+)\s+"(.*?)"\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)s\s+([\d\.]+)#s', $text, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
$users = array();
foreach($matches as $match) {
    $users[] = array(
        'id' => $match[1],
        'name' => $match[2],
        'ping' => $match[3],
        'connectedFor' => $match[4],
        'ip' => $match[5],
    );
}
var_dump($users);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, все четко. Хотя утром проверил и чет не то. Только заходя в лифт понял что ошибка тут "test name :))))))))

Comment: после #s надо еще u добавить